# Why $\frac{d}{dt}(u(t),v(t))_{H} = \langle u'(t), v(t)\rangle_{V^*,V} + \langle v'(t), u(t)\rangle_{V^*,V}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

For a Hilbert triple $V \subset H \subset V^*$, and for $u,v \in L^2(0,T;V)$ with $u',v' \in L^2(0,T;V^*)$

Why is it true that

$$\frac{d}{dt}(u(t),v(t))_{H} =  \langle u'(t), v(t)\rangle_{V^*,V} + \langle v'(t), u(t)\rangle_{V^*,V}?$$

I just saw this result on MO and tried to look in Evans but he does it for the $L^2$ case. Can someone tell me the proof? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried following the proof of $(uv)'=u'v+v'u$ and if so, where have you encountered a problem?

Comment: @5PM But $uv$ is not defined in general, right? We don't know what kind of space $H$ is.

Comment: I meant the ordinary calculus proof for real valued functions $u,v$. It proceeds through things like $u(t+h)v(t+h)-u(t)v(t) = (u(t+h)-u(t))v(t)+(v(t+h)-v(t))u(t+h)$, which apply equally well to all bilinear forms, not just scalar multiplication.

Comment: @5PM Thankyou, I will try it out.

Comment: @5PM I tried it and I get the RHS with the pairing turned into inner product in $H$. I think $\frac{d}{dt}$ is weak derivative, so we cannot do this way maybe.

Comment: Good point: the function $v$ takes values in $H$ but its derivative does not; therefore it is not the pointwise derivative. Now we should ask: how is $v'$ defined? And a likely answer is: by the identity in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. Prove the equation for $u,v \in H^1(0,T, V)$.
2. Recall that
   $$(u,v)_H = (i \, u, v)_{V^*,V}$$
   for all $u,v \in V$. Here, $i : V \to V^*$ is the embedding from $V$ into $V^*$ defined via the Hilbert triplet.
3. Now, a density argument shows that the formula holds for $u,v$ in the desired space.